# Does existence of two weak derivatives imply another one?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\alpha,\beta$ be two multi-indices. Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume $u\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$.

We know that if weak derivative $D^{\alpha+\beta}u$ exists, then $D^\alpha u$ or $D^\beta u$ may NOT exist. And if weak derivatives $D^\alpha u,D^\beta u$ exist, then $D^{\alpha+\beta}u$ may NOT exist.

The question is that if $D^{\alpha+\beta}u$ and $D^{\beta}u$ exist, then can we have $D^\alpha u$ exists?

Comment: I can't make any sense of this. First, how can $D^{\alpha+\beta}$ exist if $D^\alpha$ does not exist? Second, the hypothesis in the question assumes something you say we know cannot happen...

Comment: These derivatives are all in weak sense. It can happen that some higher order derivative exists without existence of lower order derivatives.

Comment: What's an example where that happens? (Even if that _can_ happen, it's still true that you say we know A cannot happen and then your question begins by assuming A happens - ???)

Comment: The question is no longer self-contradictory after the edit. I'd still like an example where $D^{\alpha+\beta}$ exists but $D^\alpha$ does not. You say we know this is possible - I don't know any such thing.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141768/does-the-existence-of-weak-derivatives-require-the-lower-order-derivatives-also

Comment: Thank you! I have modified this problem.