# Existence of higher weak derivative(s) implies lower

Tags: weak-derivatives

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2$ be an open set, and let $f\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ have a weak derivative $f_{xx}\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$.

1. Does this imply the existence of $f_x\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$?
2. If not, does the existence of all second-order weak derivatives (or just $f_{xx}$ and $f_{xy}$) imply it?
3. Or maybe suffices the existence of $f_{xx}$, but assuming more regularity (for example $L^p_{loc}(\Omega)$, or even $C^{0,\alpha}$)?

Things that I know:

1. Existence of highly regular $f_{xy}$ is not sufficient
2. If $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist continuous then $f\in C^1(\Omega)$, but I don't know whether it is related
3. [Does the existence of weak derivatives require the lower order derivatives also to exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141768/does-the-existence-of-weak-derivatives-require-the-lower-order-derivatives-also)